# can't connect to rds at ec2 server, missing mysql socket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an ec2 server and rds server.
and a Ruby On Rails App
connecting to the rds with these settings worked for me in local ENV:

```
host: myappnameandhash.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
reconnect: false
database: mainDb
pool: 20
username: root
password: xxxx
socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port: 3306
```

but on my EC2 server I don't have that mysqld.sock file
so i get this error:

> FATAL: failed to connect to MySQL (error=Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2))

what do i need to install in order to have the socket?

thanks

update:

I removed the socket definition and the port.
I deploy using capistrano , now i ssh to my server and go to the "current" folder. there i try to run: rake ts:start
and i get the following:

> rake aborted!
>   Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

but i don't even have the socket definition in my database.yml file anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the socket and port number from your database.yml file and then try, it will work.

Comment: still isn't working.. :( ill update my question with more stuff i see

Comment: restart the instance once n try. Also check whether you have installed my-client libraries on your instance

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the "host" of your RDS, and also configure the security groups in the RDS to allow your instance to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been a while, just encountered this issue with my EC2 server connecting to RDS. Would like to share how I resolve this.

First removing `socket` and `port` from the database.yml help

```
#In your database.yml

development:
  #some configuration

staging:
  #some configuration

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  pool: 20
  host: url.to.rds.server
  database: your-database
  username: your-username
  password: your-password
```

To run this rake command on production, you need to specify your `rails-env`, e.g. if you are using `production` environment, it should be

```
bundle exec rake ts:start RAILS_ENV=production
```